# Metaball wiggle with position fixed

Tags: animation-nodes

I am quite new to Blender.

I design an object with multiple metaballs and tried to animate it by using Animation Nodes.

I want to animate like my designed metaball is asseebled after wiggling around.

I have watched several tutorials, but I have no idea how to keep the original position of designed metaballs I placed.

Once I choose metaballs I want to animate by using 'Create Object list', it just moved to the coordinate 0,0,0 wiggles there.

Does anybody know how to do what I want to animate?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Most likely you should **add** the wiggles to each individual ball locations

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object ID Keys](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/object/object_id_key/) to store intial location.

Comment: Thanks let me try!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the initial location and add to that you have to aktivate **Delta Transforms** in *Objekt Transform Outpout > N-Panel > Advanced Node Settings > Delta Transforms*